# How to enable/disable button in activity based on checkbox checked in Custom Adapter

Tags: android

I have a button in activity which i want to disable based on checkbox that is Checked/Unchecked in custom adapter. I tried boolean but it didn't work, how do i do that?

Below is my checkbox in Adapter

Code :

```
CheckBox option_image = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.option_image);
                Log.d(TAG, "Item selected " + oi.getOptionId());
                Log.d(TAG, "Item name " + oi.getOptionName());
                Log.d(TAG, "Item subid " + oi.getSubid());
                Log.d(TAG, "state is " + oi.isSelected());
                    if (oi.isSelected()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "enable now");
                        option_image.setChecked(true);
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "disable now");
                        option_image.setChecked(false);
                    }

                option_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                            ifchecked = true;
                            Log.d("Button", "Checked");

                        }
                      else{
                            Log.d("Button", "Unchecked Checked");

                      }}
                });
```

Below is my Button in Activity

```
  button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnManualLookup);
  button.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: can you please post what you did?

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: @Manikanta - I have checkbox in adapter where i am getting whether the checkbox is checked or not, now if checked i want my button to be enabled in activity, if not checked i will disable it, but not sure how can i do that? I tried setting boolean in adapter but it won't work as when activity will launch the boolean will be null

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi - Have updated code

Comment: if(checkbox.isChecked){ button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); }  if(!checkbox.isChecked){ button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); }

Comment: Note : The layout for both is different. That's my struggle

Comment: @ChiragSavsani - I could have done that easily if the button was in same layout where my checkbox is, but layout is different

Comment: Use ImageView instead of checkBox and maitain a boolen in your bean class for each row

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi - Can i not get instance of activity layout ?

Comment: where are you doing this whole functionality in custom adapter ?

Comment: create your adapter class inside of your activity class. then problem will solved.

Answer (score 0):

try this code for enable or desable

```
button.setEnabled(false);
button.setEnabled(true);
```

or

```
button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

or in xml file you can also set visibility

```
android:enabled="false"
android:enabled="true"
```